Chrome extension, Root.render() seem to not work when manipulate browser's DOM
When trying to manipulate the DOM in the current tab's browser, root.render() doesn't seem to work. The inline method using innerHTML works, but I can't figure out why root.render() is not functioning.
I've posted a GitHub issue about this. Could you please take a look?
github issue: https://github.com/sae1013/react-chrome-extension/issues/1
When clicking the "Open Note" button in the popup, I want to display a fixed modal at the bottom right of the current browser
